# How do I get TextMate to auto-expand when I close the project drawer?

Tags: textmate, usability

So when I press control-option-command-D to open/close the project drawer, the window doesn't go back to maximum size as it was before.

Is there a way to enable this?  This is for TextMate 1.5.11.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could try [ProjectPlus](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/08/29/projectplus-update-2) or [MissingDrawer](https://github.com/jezdez/textmate-missingdrawer).

Answer (score 0):

TextMate 2.0 has shortcut to show/hide file browser if you are willing to upgrade. I think upgrade is also free for 1.5 users.